# Conditional Cartesian product of lists in itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have four lists:

```
LISTA = ['A1', 'A2']
LISTB = ['B1_C', 'B2_D']
LISTC = ['C1', 'C2']
LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']
```

I'd like to get the Cartesian product of `LISTA` and `LISTB`, and then depending on the value of B, I'd like to add either the product of C, or the product of D.

```
(A1 B1_C C1)
(A1 B1_C C2)
(A2 B1_C C1)
(A2 B1_C C2)
(A1 B2_D D1)
(A1 B2_D D2)
(A2 B2_D D1)
(A2 B2_D D2)
```

I can get the first part with `itertools.product(LISTA, LISTB)`, but I've been looking through [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for how to achieve the second part and I'm not sure the best way to go. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interactive demonstration of a solution using a generator.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> LISTA = ['A1', 'A2']
>>> LISTB = ['B1_C', 'B2_D']
>>> LISTC = ['C1', 'C2']
>>> LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']
>>> def C_OR_D(P):
...    for a,b in P:
...      for x in {"C":LISTC, "D":LISTD}[b[-1]]:
...         yield a,b,x
... 
>>> for t in C_OR_D(itertools.product(LISTA,LISTB)):
...    print t
... 
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')
```

---

Note that the order is different then what [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3506260/michael) requested because the second component in `product(LISTA,LISTB)` changes faster then the first.

To get the exact ordering specified we need the reversed results from `product(LISTB,LISTA)`.  E.g.

```
>>> for t in C_OR_D((a,b) for (b,a) in itertools.product(LISTB,LISTA)):
...    print t
... 
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')
```

Note also that this approach allows `LISTC` and `LISTD` to have unequal length. E.g.

```
>>> LISTD = ['D1', 'D2', 'D3']
>>> for t in C_OR_D((a,b) for (b,a) in itertools.product(LISTB,LISTA)):
...    print t
... 
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D3')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D3')
```

Comment: The order of your tuples is not the same as the one describe by the OP.

Comment: Thanks - I've made a note and added an example which returns the requested ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the *product* replacing the last two lists with a **`range`** object of equal length, and then select either of the last two lists depending on the last character of the item from `LISTB`:

```
from itertools import product

def func(lsta, lstb, lstc, lstd):
    for b, a, i in product(lstb, lsta, range(len(lstc))):
        yield a, b, lstc[i] if b.endswith('C') else lstd[i]

for tup in func(LISTA, LISTB, LISTC, LISTD):          
    print(tup)
```

---

```
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1')
('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1')
('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools, I think this should do the work:

```
import itertools

LISTA = ['A1', 'A2']
LISTB = ['B1_C', 'B2_D']
LISTC = ['C1', 'C2']
LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']
res = []

dictb = {b:b.split("_")[1] for b in LISTB}

def product_for(lst, b, otherlst, result):
    for el in itertools.product(*[lst , [b] , otherlst]):
      result.append(el)

for k,v in dictb.items():
  if v == 'C':
    product_for(LISTA, k, LISTC,res)
  else:
    product_for(LISTA, k, LISTD,res)

print(res)

=> [('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1'), ('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2'), ('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1'), ('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2'), ('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1'), ('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2'), ('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1'), ('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')]
```

Comment: I'm not tied to itertools so if you know a way without that's better then that would also be good :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a go at it. So you know the first part:

```
part1 = itertools.product(LISTA, LISTB)
```

Which results in:

```
[('A1', 'B1_C'), ('A1', 'B2_D'), ('A2', 'B1_C'), ('A2', 'B2_D')]
```

You could then group by the last character of the last element of each tuple:

```
keyfunc = lambda x: x[1][-1:]
grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(part1, key=keyfunc), keyfunc)    
# convert group object to dictionary
grouped_dict = dict((k, list(v)) for k, v in grouped)
```

That gives you this:

```
{'C': [('A1', 'B1_C'), ('A2', 'B1_C')], 'D': [('A1', 'B2_D'), ('A2', 'B2_D')]}
```

Now you can do a product on each group, and join them back up:

```
c = itertools.product(grouped_dict['C'], LISTC)
d = itertools.product(grouped_dict['D'], LISTD)    
part2 = itertools.chain(c, d)
```

Which leaves you with:

```
[(('A1', 'B1_C'), 'C1'),
 (('A1', 'B1_C'), 'C2'),
 (('A2', 'B1_C'), 'C1'),
 (('A2', 'B1_C'), 'C2'),
 (('A1', 'B2_D'), 'D1'),
 (('A1', 'B2_D'), 'D2'),
 (('A2', 'B2_D'), 'D1'),
 (('A2', 'B2_D'), 'D2')]
```

Finally, you can flatten each element again:

```
part2 = itertools.imap(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1],), part2)
```

Which gets you the final result:

```
[('A1', 'B1_C', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B1_C', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B1_C', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B1_C', 'C2'),
 ('A1', 'B2_D', 'D1'),
 ('A1', 'B2_D', 'D2'),
 ('A2', 'B2_D', 'D1'),
 ('A2', 'B2_D', 'D2')]
```

[Here](https://repl.it/N7KG/0)'s the code if you want to play with it.