# Conditional Cartesian product of a X lists, resulting in dict with k,v pairs?

Tags: python, python-itertools, nested-lists

I have a number of lists as follows:

```
LISTA = ['A1', 'A2']
LISTB = ['B1', 'B2']
LISTC = ['C1']
LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']
LISTE = ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']
```

I'd like to write a function to get the Cartesian product of `LISTX` and `LISTY`, and then depending on the value of `LISTY` in each tuple, I'd like to add either the product of `LISTJ`, or the product of `LISTK`. All as named key/value pairs, or as lists where `[0]` is the key and `[1]` is the value.

i.e. If `X == LISTA`, `Y == LISTB`, `J == LISTC`, `K == LISTE`, and we assume if there is value `B1` we get the product with `J(LISTC)` and `B2` we get the product with `K(LISTE)`, then we should get something like...

```
[{'LISTA': A1, 'LISTB': B1 'LISTC': C1},
 {'LISTA': A1, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E1},
 {'LISTA': A1, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E2},
 {'LISTA': A1, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E3},
 {'LISTA': A2, 'LISTB': B1 'LISTC': C1},
 {'LISTA': A2, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E1},
 {'LISTA': A2, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E2},
 {'LISTA': A2, 'LISTB': B2 'LISTE': E3}]
```

I think it's probably something along these lines, where we first get the product, and then use a generator in order to return a dict for each tuple in that product, along with the assigned `k,v` pair from `j` or `k`. However, I can't figure out how to make this more generic than having 'y_val' in the arguments, and I'm also not sure how to assign the keys in `J_OR_K`, rather than just ending up with a tuple like `(('LISTA', A1), ('LISTB', B1), C1)`.

```
import itertools as it

def J_OR_K(P, y_val1, y_val2, j_list, k_list):
    for k, v in P:
        for x in {y_val1:j_list, y_val2:k_list}[v]:
            yield {a,b,x}

def my_func(x, y, j, k):
    res = []
    # get cartesian product of x, y
    prod_xy = it.product(it.product(['LISTA'], x), 
                         it.product(['LISTB'], y))
    # get product with EITHER J OR K
    for t in J_OR_K(j, k):
        res.append(t)
```

Although this is similar to a question I've previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043660/conditional-cartesian-product-of-lists-in-itertools), this is moderately different and more involved - so felt it required a new question.

Comment: One problem I see is that the name of the lists in the parameters `j_list` and `k_list` can't be determined (because only the lists itself are available). Possible solutions: (1) a class derived from list which also hold its name or (2) additional parameters for list names.

Comment: `LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']` appears superfluous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interactive demonstration of a solution:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> LISTA = ['A1', 'A2']
>>> LISTB = ['B1', 'B2']
>>> LISTC = ['C1']
>>> LISTD = ['D1', 'D2']
>>> LISTE = ['E1', 'E2', 'E3']
>>> def f():
...    for a,b in itertools.product(LISTA,LISTB):
...       n, l = {"B1":["LISTC",LISTC], "B2":["LISTE",LISTE]}[b]
...       for x in l:
...          yield {"LISTA":a, "LISTB":b, n:x}
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(f()))
[{'LISTA': 'A1', 'LISTB': 'B1', 'LISTC': 'C1'},
 {'LISTA': 'A1', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E1'},
 {'LISTA': 'A1', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E2'},
 {'LISTA': 'A1', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E3'},
 {'LISTA': 'A2', 'LISTB': 'B1', 'LISTC': 'C1'},
 {'LISTA': 'A2', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E1'},
 {'LISTA': 'A2', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E2'},
 {'LISTA': 'A2', 'LISTB': 'B2', 'LISTE': 'E3'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following nested comprehension works to the desired effect for your example:

```
>>> from itertools import product as p
>>> [x + y for x in p(LISTA, LISTB) for y in p(LISTC if x[1] == 'B1' else LISTE)]
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'E1'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'E2'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'E3'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'E1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'E2'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'E3')]
```